# Does your average web user understand the concept of the clipboard?

Tags: user-interface, web

I'm designing a web site where I would expect the intended audience to have limited computer skills.

An important part of my site's functionality will require the end user to copy an URL that my site generates and use it in emails, or social network postings, or on their own web site.

I could write the URL to the clipboard when a button is pushed (like tinyurl.com does). However I'm wondering whether the average user even understands what that means and how to use it.

Any guidence will be appreciated.

Comment: This might be a good question for the User Experience Stack Exchange site: http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to conduct usability tests on a sampling of your target audience.

Answer (score 0):

There are several paths of though possible, you can make many of the scenarios possible at once.

- Make the URL copied at once.
- Make the URL copied when pushing the button.
- Make the URL selected at once so the user can copy it directly

Of course since the URL is copied at once the two other actions does not need to do anything with the clipboard unless the user has modified the clipboard after the URL was presented.

When the URL is copied, at least in the first two steps you could show a message for the user that is has been copied, that makes it useful for those that understand it.
For those that might be focused on copying the URL themselves step 3 helps them on their way.

Whatever path the user tries should go as smooth as possible without forcing them to understand the benefits offered. In the long run it might help them, but if only used a few times the work of understanding what is going on outweighs the benefit.